# Migrate angular *ngFor and *ngIf to new v17 syntax?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-migration, angular17

I'm migrating from angular 16 to 17 and I encountered the issue that I need to replace all the usages of `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` and `ngSwitch` with the new syntax (`@for` and `@if` and `@switch`).

I know the v17 still supports the old syntax but is there a way to migrate them or a regex to replace them with the new form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can migrate your angular project control flow with this command:

```
ng g @angular/core:control-flow
```

It will take a path and migrate the entire files (including subdirectories) to the new control flow.

> This command is still in developer review but it worked fine for my project.